# Specify which directory for spring boot devtools live reload to watch in maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-devtools

I am working on a simple web app to serve some HTML and static files in a Spring Boot maven project. I am using Spring Boot devtools with Live Reload Chrome extension to help with the development process.

My maven project is pretty simple, as described in the screenshot. There's a `src` directory and a `target` directory, but the live reloader is only detecting changes in the `target` directory. This means that if I want live reload on my HTML files, I need to edit them in the `target/classes` directory. This is not ideal, since `mvn clean` will clear out the `target` directory.

[image]

I want Spring Boot to reload the page when changes are made in the `src/main/resources` directory, not just `target`.

How do I tell Spring Boot live reloader to watch the `src/main/resources` directory instead of just the `target/classes` directory?

Comment: Check the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.4/reference/htmlsingle/#using.devtools